# How do you use force adb to backup without user confirmation?

Tags: android, backup, adb, fastboot

Running `adb backup -apk -shared -all` on an Android device yields `Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation.` on the Terminal and a prompt on the device screen that requires user intervention. I was hoping to automate backup and restore from adb. is there a way to force and proceed with backup without user confirmation?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This can be done using `fastboot` command by pulling data off the inactive Android device. Here's a sample tutorial on this at [XDA University](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2290009).

Comment: In the link you posted, I cannot find instructions to do a backup using fastboot. It only instructs, how to create update.zip-files (including scripts) to modify something on the device as far as I can see. Could you please post the steps needed here? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this case is to use `dd` (it's available in vanilla Android, and custom recoveries, like TWRP, as well):

```
sudo adb shell dd if=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/boot > boot.bin
sudo adb shell dd if=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/modem > modem.bin
sudo adb shell dd if=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system > system.bin
```

...Or with compression:

```
sudo adb shell dd if=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system | xz -9 -T0 - > system.bin.xz
```

Later the binary image can be transformed to any desired backup format.